# Permanently remove remote origin-http

Tags: git

I switched to using SSH for my git repository. Somehow, git is still tracking origin-http though. This is annoying, because whenever I want to checkout a remote branch, I can't just run `git checkout <branch-name>`, I have to do `remotes/origin/<branch-name>` because there's two repos with that branch name (origin and origin-http)

When I run `git remote -v`, I see:

```
origin (fetch)
origin (push)
origin-http (fetch)
origin-http (push)
```

If I run `git remote remove origin-http` it appears to do nothing. I.e, when I do `git remote` right after, it still shows origin-http.

How can I permanently remove origin-http?

For the record, I'm using cmder on Windows10

Comment: Hey Ethan, could you possibly provide a use case of when the origin-http comes back?

Comment: Yep, I'll try to pinpoint exactly when it happens and get back to you

Comment: @Gerik I believe it comes back when I run git fetch

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git config -l --show-origin` and look for any instance of `origin-http`.

If a branch is [tracking `origin-http/abranch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309) (instead of `origin/abranch`), you need to change that too (and not just remove the remote named '`origin-http`')

Beside that, look for any hook  (`.git/hooks/` folder) or `.gitattributes` directive that would execute automatically (like a pre-commit hook), and add that strangely named remote back.

Comment: In my case, when I run that, it shows file: .git/config remote.origin AND file: .git/config remote.origin-http